# Backbone.js, why this callback is fired multiple times?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I have a simple popover module that can be added to another view. This popover should listen for clicks or mouseups outside of his own view.

```
function(app) {
  var Popover = app.module();
  Popover.Views.Default = Backbone.View.extend({
    className: 'popover',
    initialize: function(options) {
      _.bindAll(this, 'hideOutsideClick');
      this.on('toggle', this.toggle);
      this.render();
    },
    afterRender: function() {
      //watch for clicks outside current view
      $('html').on('click', this.hideOutsideClick);
    },
    remove: function() {
      //cleanup
      this.hide(); 
      $('html').off('click', this.hideOutsideClick); this.$el.remove();
    },
    show: function() {
      this.visible = true; this.$el.show();     
    },
    hide: function() {
      this.$el.hide(); this.visible = false;
    },
    toggle: function() {
      this.visible ? this.hide() : this.show();
    },
    hideOutsideClick: function(event){
     //on any click this is fired 4 times!!!
    }
  });
  return Popover;
});
```

My problem is that the hideOutsideCallback is fired 4 times when a click is performed. Why?

Comment: I edited my answer, mey be it useful for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved most issues and provide a working popover module here http://pastebin.com/HF5gSUKQ

To listen for clicks outside the current view:

```
_.bindAll(this, 'hideOutsideClick');
 $('html').on('click', this.hideOutsideClick);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a backdrop like bootstrap modal does. The backdrop consumes the whole space of the site and when it gets clicked it closes the modal.

Comment: I think this is not an option. Just think of an use case where the user clicks another button while popover is visible.

Comment: sure, this would only make sense if the backdrop is translucent black or something like that. If I display a modal the user should interact with that and should not be able to do other things on the page.

Comment: by the way, I think I misunderstood you. You mean popovers not modals right?

Answer (score 0):

if I had understood perfectly your question, You can do like this:

**First way**

```
         --------
        |  view  |
         --------
             |
      --------------     
     |              |
 ----------      ----------
| subview1 |    | subview2 |
 ----------      ----------
```

and inside view You can write(or initialize) all events which are bellow to subviews(subview1 and subview2).

**Second way** is that: You create global `object`, inside view1's `intialize` you need to bind event like this:

```
object.any_field.on('change', this.anyFunction())
```

and inside view2 You must to change `object.any_field`

**Edit**

```
initialize: function(options) {
    this.off() 
    _.bindAll(this, 'hideOutsideClick');
    this.on('toggle', this.toggle);
    this.render();
}
```